# JQuery: div slide to occupy full page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

We have a product page that we are dividing in two. My goal is to make it so that when you click one of the divs it slides to fill the whole page and show the products.

http://jsfiddle.net/Sj575/

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div id="green" class="type1">Exterior products</div>
    <div id="red" class="type2">Interior products</div>    
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.type1 {
    width:300px;
    background-color:green;
    display:inline-block;
    height:320px;
}
.type2{
    width:300px;
    background-color:red;
    display:inline-block;
    height:320px;   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the following jQuery (and some html/css changes), you get this: http://jsfiddle.net/Sj575/274/

```
$(function() {
 $(".green").click(function() {

    $(".red").toggleClass("hidden");
    $(".green").toggleClass("full")

});

$(".red").click(function() {

    $(".green").toggleClass("hidden");
    $(".red").toggleClass("full")

 });
});
```

EDIT: Here's another one that slides in instead, http://jsfiddle.net/Sj575/277/

Comment: this is exacly what i needed, with the option to click back to normal
Apreciate it very much

Answer (score 1):

Try this. ;)

http://jsfiddle.net/ph31wyy3/1/

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div id="green" class="green block">eezez</div>
    <div id="red" class="red block">eezez</div>    
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.green {
    width:400px;
    background-color:green;
    display:block;
    height:320px;
  float: left;
}
.red{
    width:200px;
    background-color:red;
    display:block;
    height:320px;   
  float: left;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
   $('.block').on('click', function(){
      $('.block').not(this).animate({'width' : '0' }, 500, function() { $(this).hide(); });
      $(this).animate({'width' : '100%'}, 500);
   });
});
```

Comment: The only problem is that it doesn´t go back to normal, but it helped too, thank you for your time :D 
Cheers!